# Python snmp OID values

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp, mib

Im using this script to get memory and cpu statics

'''

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
           UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 3161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0')),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.10.0')),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10.1.3.3')))
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

'''

I'm getting the following output

[image: Response values]

However, I only need the actual values outputted that are in the far right, and save them as float or int values.

Comment: Based on your code, it looks like `varBind` may be a list, with the second item being the value you want.

Comment: You're totally right, preciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you can repalce:

```
for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

by

```
for oid, val in varBinds:
    print(oid.prettyPrint(),' = ', val.prettyPrint())
```